# /opt folder no longer accessible in finder on Catalina

Tags: macos, finder, catalina

I have always been able to save to the `/opt` folder. I recently upgraded to macOS Catalina and can no longer see this folder.

In Finder I am able to display hidden folders and I can see it once again. However, when going to the Save As dialog in various programs I cannot see it there.

How can I make `/opt` visible again?

Comment: In the heading you write that it is no longer accessible in Finder, but in the text you write that you *can* see it in Finder. Which is it? You also state that you can't see it in "various programs". Can you give some examples of those programs? (FWIW, I can see my /opt folder in Text Editor and Safari *if* I type command-shift-. to display hidden stuff.)

Comment: By no longer accessible, I mean it is no longer accessible by default unless I show hidden files. Also, yes, I can see it with command-shift-. in other programs. I did not realize I can do this. Still it is a nuisance. Is there a way just to make the /opt folder to be not hidden?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you are using `/System/Volumes/Data/opt` instead of `/opt`, because the later is not writable due to security features. If you are sure the folder is on the data partition, then `chflags nohidden /System/Volumes/Data/opt` should unhide it.

Answer (score 1):

macOS Catalina splits the boot volume into two distinct components, named Startup and Data. It runs off of a read-only filesystem, which is separate from the data files. So even if you find `/opt`, you may not be able to write to it.

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT210650

To access and write to it, try going to `/System/Volumes/Data/opt` using Finder or Terminal. In Finder, you can user the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to bring **Go To Folder...** mini window, and enter the location.

Answer (score 0):

```
chflags nohidden /System/Volumes/Data/opt

setfile -a v /System/Volumes/Data/opt
```

Comment: As fyi, `/usr/bin/SetFile` or `setfile` was deprecated with Xcode 6 along as were other tools supporting Carbon development; although `SetFile` still appears to install as part of Xcode 12 additional command line tools. `man SetFile` for info.